# What are the HKUnits available for HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCarbohydrates and where should I have found this information?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I've been working with HealthKit for some time, but I somehow can't find a definitive reference listing what units are available for each kind of sample type. Where can I find this info? Or if there is no definitive link, can someone tell me the units available for `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCarbohydrates`? Much obliged!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's super easy to tell which unit types are compatible with a given quantity type! If you go to HKTypeIdentifiers.h, then you will see the type identifiers listed like this:

```
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCarbohydrates NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);      // Mass,   Cumulative
```

The comment at the end of the line shows that it is a cumulative quantity type that uses mass units. If you're not sure which units are considered mass units, you can go to HKUnit.h. There's a lot of good information there, but the piece that's relevant to this is:

```
/* Mass Units */
@interface HKUnit (Mass)
+ (instancetype)gramUnitWithMetricPrefix:(HKMetricPrefix)prefix;       // g
+ (instancetype)gramUnit;   // g
+ (instancetype)ounceUnit;  // oz
+ (instancetype)poundUnit;  // lb
+ (instancetype)stoneUnit;  // st
+ (instancetype)moleUnitWithMetricPrefix:(HKMetricPrefix)prefix molarMass:(double)gramsPerMole;   // mol<double>
+ (instancetype)moleUnitWithMolarMass:(double)gramsPerMole; // mol<double>
@end
```